# replace a div containing a data grid with another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace the `inboxcontent` div with the `outboxcontent` div on button click of `btnOUtbox` and also reverting back on click of `btnInbox`.
Both Divs displays a datagrid with values. Which is the best method?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnInbox").click(function (e) {
      $("#OutboxContent").css("visibility", "hidden");
      $("#InboxContent").css("visibility", "visible");
      $("#InboxContent").show();

      alert("replced ");
    });

    $("#btnOutbox").click(function (e) {
      $("#InboxContent").css("visibility", "hidden");
      $("#OutboxContent").css("visibility", "visible");
      $('#InboxContent').replaceWith($('#OutboxContent'));
      alert("replced ");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You can show and hide it in click event as per your requirement instead of changing the visibility and replacing content. BtnInbox - Inbox.Show(); Outbox.Hide() and BtnOutbox- Inbox.Hide(); Outbox.Show()

Comment: i tried that but its not working. I want both the divs in same position. The Second div is far below the first one.

Comment: @SridharNarasimhan I tried this... only the contents of first div is showing up. The second div gets blank.

Comment: Please post your html or post a fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the display property to hide and show divs."display:none" will hide the div and will not allocate space for the element.
visibility:hidden will hide the element,but will allocate the space for the element in the page.